# Vue Loader Can't resolve '@'

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

#### Version

15.4.0

#### Reproduction link

https://codepen.io/fendi-tri-cahyono/pen/wbXKMZ?editors=0010

#### Steps to reproduce

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-extend-layout/vue-extend-layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-extend-layout/vue-extend-layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@' in '/Users/fenditricahyono/Projects/titipbeliin/titipbeliin-vue/node_modules/vue-extend-layout'
 @ ./node_modules/vue-extend-layout/vue-extend-layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-extend-layout/vue-extend-layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 50:19-96
 @ ./node_modules/vue-extend-layout/vue-extend-layout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./node_modules/vue-extend-layout/vue-extend-layout.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
```

#### What is expected?

can resove for 
import Something from '@/something.vue', 
not only 
import Something from '../../something.vue',

#### What is actually happening?

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@' in '/Users/fenditricahyono/Projects/titipbeliin/titipbeliin-vue/node_modules/vue-extend-layout'

Comment: The `@` alias in Vue CLI v3 projects comes from the [default `resolve` configuration for Webpack](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js#L51). Is your project created / built using Vue CLI v3? Your _"Steps to reproduce"_ doesn't appear to have any **steps**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Phil's comment, I'm assuming you didn't initialize the project with Vue CLI (by the look of your webpack config), what you are looking for should be an alias (represented with the `@` symbol that is commonly used and/or produced by the CLI) that maps to the root path of your project directory. So try adding the following extra line under the [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) object:

```js
{
  // ...

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // Relative path to your root dir (adjust accordingly)
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),

      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  },

  // ...
}
```